# How to extract the Bitmap out of the onDraw() method of a View?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-bitmap

How can I extract a `Bitmap` object out of my `onDraw()` routine in my CustomView?

Here is my code:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Point point;
    private LinkedList<Point> listaPontos;
    private static Context context;

    class Point {

        public Point(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
    }

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        this.context = context;
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        this.listaPontos = new LinkedList<Point>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if(listaPontos.size() != 0){
            for(Point point : listaPontos){
                canvas.drawCircle(point.x,  point.y, 25, paint);    
            }
        }
        calculateAmount(canvas);        
    }

    private void calculateAmount(Canvas canvas) {
        LinkedList<Integer> colors = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i != canvas.getWidth(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j != canvas.getHeight(); j++){

                int color = BITMAP.getPixel(i,j);  //How can I get the bitmap generated on onDraw ?

                colors.add(color);
            }
        }

        int yellow = 0;
        int white = 0;

        for(Integer cor : colors) {

            if(cor == Color.WHITE) {
                white++;
            }
            if(cor == Color.YELLOW) {
                yellow++;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    listaPontos.add(new Point(event.getX(), event.getY()));
                    break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks alot in advance ;)

EDIT: The bitmap thing is to calculate each pixel color, how can I add a background image to my DrawView ? I tested this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a); at constructor but didn't work, thanks again ;)

Comment: You can set background images in .xml as well. Simply set android:background="@drawable/your_drawable". Also be aware that drawn stuff in your DrawView might overlay the background image.

Comment: I am not using the xml , the mBitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); was erasing the content, I now added the image using Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);  mBitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, paint);    but the image gets stretched down.. not maximized why?

Comment: Here is how to load a Bitmap correctly from the resources: http://pastebin.com/LsEWpSMq  simply use Bitmap b = BitmapResloader.decodeBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight);  Also, please select my answer as correct if it answered the original question.

Comment: Yes, alternatively you can browse stack overflow for related questions or open a new question concerning your problem with the bitmap decoding and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no way to extract a Bitmap out of a Canvas.** At least not directly.

However, it is possible to **draw on a Bitmap** with the `Canvas` and then use the `Bitmap`.

```
Bitmap mDrawBitmap;
Canvas mBitmapCanvas;
Paint drawPaint = new Paint();

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    drawPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

    if (mDrawBitmap == null) {
        mDrawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mDrawBitmap);
    }

    // clear previously drawn stuff
    mBitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    // draw on the btimapCanvas
    mBitmapCanvas.drawStuff(...);
    //... and more

    // after drawing with the bitmapcanvas,
    //all drawn information is stored in the Bitmap    


    // draw everything to the screen
    canvas.drawBitmap(mDrawBitmap, 0, 0, drawPaint);
}
```

After the `onDraw()` method has finished, all drawn information will be drawn on the screen (by calling `canvas.drawBitmap(...)`, and also be stored in your `Bitmap` object (because all draw operations have been done on the `Canvas` that was created with the `Bitmap`).

Comment: Where is the object bitmapCanvas ? did you misstyped ? is the mBitmapCanvas?

Comment: I will test if I can do it now, i will accept if everything went okay. thanks by the way for the answer :)

Comment: You are welcome. Don't hesitate to ask if there are any further questions. I typed this code by "mind", so no copy paste. Letz see if this compiles :)
What are you trying to do with the bitmap?

Comment: It worked thanks alot, I will ask a new question related to this editing the main post, check it please.